# In Meteor, how do I attach a Template Event to a dynamically inserted element?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a Meteor template event where I'm inserting a `<div class="mask"></div>` on click...

```
Template.dGlobalNav.events({

    "click .toggle-slide-left": function() {
      var mask = document.createElement("div");
      mask.className = "mask";

      $("body").addClass("sml-open");
      document.body.appendChild(mask);
      Session.set("activeNav", "sml-open");
    },
```

...I'd then like to attach another click event to this `<div class="mask"></div>`...

```
"click .mask": function() {
  $("body").removeClass(Session.get("activeNav"));
  Session.set("activeNav", "");
  $(".mask").remove();
}
```

Which all together leaves me with this block:

```
Template.dGlobalNav.events({

"click .toggle-slide-left": function() {
  var mask = document.createElement("div");
  mask.className = "mask";

  $("body").addClass("sml-open");
  document.body.appendChild(mask);
  Session.set("activeNav", "sml-open");
},

"click .mask": function() {
  $("body").removeClass(Session.get("activeNav"));
  Session.set("activeNav", "");
  $(".mask").remove();
}
```

});

However, it seems like the `"click .mask"` function isn't firing at all. I suspect this has to do with the fact that the first click event handler generated the `.mask` element in the first place...but after lots of desperate Googling I can't find how (or even if) it's possible for me to attach an Template event handler to a dynamically inserted HTML element.

I'm sure I'm doing something (or many things) wrong here, so any help or points in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of your code the added `mask` div is not added into the template `dGlobalNav` that has the `"click .mask"` event function on it. It is added to the body tag. Therefore it will not fire. I am not sure where you want it, but if you add it to a div thats inside the template it will fire.

I've added this div in the template `dGlobalNav` HTML.

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

Then I used jQuery to add the mask div into this div.

```
//document.body.appendChild(mask);
$(mask).appendTo("#test");
```

If you have not removed it you will have jQuery available.

Comment: Ah! You were right on, the issue was that the .mask div was not in the dGlobalNav template...thanks so much!